# Integral Test "proof". Why can't it be inconclusive? Can't I draw the boxes above or below the function?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Integral test = Integral converges then series converges.    Integral diverges then series diverges.

For the proof of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ they draw the boxes starting at 0, and the boxes are drawn under the function $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$.   So, when the integral converges, so do the lesser rectangles (series).

For the proof of $\frac{1}{n}$ they draw the boxes starting at 1, and the boxes are drawn above the function $y=\frac{1}{x}$.   So, when the integral diverges, so do the higher rectangles (series).

But, why can't you just draw the boxes starting at 0, like the first example, and show the series to be lower than the divergent series, thereby being inconclusive?

https://www.google.com/search?q=integral+test+1/x%5E2&sxsrf=AJOqlzXIi6emtqWZdD0jNqwWurCqfHuXVw:1679065612754&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiyhpzrnuP9AhXgjIkEHTZrDYkQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1366&bih=625

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Integral_Test.svg/1200px-Integral_Test.svg.png
https://philschatz.com/calculus-book/resources/CNX_Calc_Figure_09_03_004.jpg

Comment: Lower than divergent might converge.  You would rather conclude something useful, and omitting a few finite terms won't affect the final verdict on the series.

Comment: You can do the test in the less useful way and learn nothing. It's not wrong, it's just not helpful.

Comment: You would like to determine whether an animal is a dog or a cat.  By applying the "does it bark or meow" test, you conclude that it is a dog.  However, why didn't you apply the "does it have four limbs" test, thereby being inconclusive?

Comment: I am missing something basic.  What I am confused about is how you can line up the boxes where you want.  I guess it's deliberately chosen based on knowing if the integral converges or diverges.   If integral converges, then I deliberately draw the boxes below, and vice versa?

Comment: The basic thing you're missing is just that there's (most of the time) no point in describing what you tried that didn't work. The first person to try apply the integral test to those series, might have tried other alignments than describe, but when they didn't tell them anything they just went on and tried something else, that then did tell them something.

Comment: So, you first determine the integral.  Based on that, you just understand that you can align the boxes to fit what you need.  Lower than convergent or higher than divergent.  The one extra box shift is moot.  Yea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, why can't you just draw the boxes starting at 0, like the first example, and show the series to be lower than the divergent series, thereby being inconclusive?

You definitely *can* do this. But it will not let you conclude anything. So there is no *reason* to do it.

There are two versions of the integral test, one where the boxes are below the curve, and one where they are above. For any given curve, depending on whether the integral of that curve converges or not, only one of those two versions lets you conclude anything about the series. That doesn't mean you can't try the other variation, but it does mean it would be entirely useless.

Answer (score 0):

The test says:

- IF Lower than convergent, THEN convergent.
- IF Higher than divergent, THEN divergent.

The test does **not** say **anything** about what we can conclude from a series that is higher than some other convergent function, or lower than some divergent series.

Remember, the test says **nothing** in those cases. If a series is higher than some convergent function, then it could still be convergent, or it could be divergent. That is what "inconclusive" means. If a test for convergence is *inconclusive* on some series, that does not mean the series is divergent!

---

Think of it this way. Let's say I have a bar that is 2m above the ground. Note that if someone can bump their head onto the bar, they obviously must be at least 2m tall, right? Since they can just walk into the bar at that point (assuming they can walk, which we do for the purpose of this explanation).

Now I have two people in the room. I ask them to try to hit the bar with their head. Person A can do it, person B cannot. From that, which of the four statements am I allowed to conclude?

- A is at least 2m tall
- B is at least 2m tall
- A is shorter than 2m
- B is shorter than 2m.

I can **only** conclude the fourth statement. If person B were 2m tall, they definitely could have bumped the bar, but they cannot, therefore they are shorter than 2m.

I cannot say **anything** about person A. Maybe they are tall, maybe they just have strong enough legs to jump high enough.

Comment: I am missing something basic.  What I am confused about is how you can line up the boxes where you want.  I guess it's deliberately chosen based on knowing if the integral converges or diverges.   If integral converges, then I deliberately draw the boxes below, and vice versa?

Comment: @JackOfAll You don't align the boxes, you select the function. The test says: "Here are the boxes. If you can draw **some** function **above** the boxes such that the function's integral will converge, then the series will converge. If you can draw **some** function **below** them such that the function's integral will diverge, then the series will diverge"

Comment: So, you first determine the integral.  Based on that, you just understand that you can align the boxes to fit what you need.  Lower than convergent or higher than divergent.  The one extra box shift is moot.  Yea?